# check object equals data stored in object in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an IPAdress.java class which has a constructor with int array to store IP address. I have to check that the object passed as parameter equals the IP address stored in the object.
I tried something like this:

```
    public boolean isTheSame(IPAdress p){
        if(????) {
            return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    }
```

And I have another method where I create the object

```
    public static IPAdress fromString(String ipStr) {
    int[] arr = new int[4];
    String[] split = ipStr.split("\\.");
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        arr[i]=Integer.parseInt(split[i]);
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
    IPAdress p = new IPAdress (arr);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Show us your `IPAdress` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have so way of getting the internal representation (e.g., let's assume your method is called `asArray()`, you can use [java.util.Arrays.equals(int[], int[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(int[],%20int[]))):

```
public boolean isTheSame(IPAdress p) {
    return Arrays.equals(asArray(), p.asArray());
}
```

EDIT:
BTW, Note that the canonical Java way of doing this would be to override `eauls(Object)`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof IPAddress) {
        return false;
    }
    return Arrays.equals(asArray(), ((IPAddress) o).asArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of your `isTheSame()` method. Just use the inbuilt equals method which designed for the same purpose.

Override the equals method in your IPAdress class and provide your implementation there to check the equality. For ex: return true if both objects ip is same etc ...

Answer (score 1):

So you can implement the interface Comparable  ,  you class IPAddress will be :
public class IPAddess implements Comparable  , then you should implement the  methods

```
@Override 
public int compareTo(IPAddress ipAddress) {  }
@Override 
public boolean equals(Object obj) {  }
A class that overrides equals must also override hashCode.
@Override 
public int hashCode()
```